# Interaction for QED with charged, scalar particles

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be the Lagrangian for usual QED with scalar, charged particles (with photons and electrons as well):

$$\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+\bar{\psi}\left(i\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}-m \right)\psi - \partial_{\mu}\phi^*\partial^{\mu}\phi-M^2\phi^*\phi$$

I was trying to show that, because of symmetries, that the Lagrangian above could be written in the same way if $\partial_{\mu} \to D_{\mu}$. However, I have to find $D_{\mu}$. The symmetry I am considering is such that

$$\psi \to \psi e^{i\Lambda(x)}$$
$$\phi \to \phi e^{i\Lambda(x)}$$
$$A_{\mu}  \to A_{\mu}-\frac{1}{e}\partial_{\mu}\Lambda(x)$$

*My attempt*

Since $\psi$ and $\phi$ have no crossed terms between them, I figured that we should add a $\mathcal{L}_{int}$ (interactions) such that it would cancel the term

$$-e\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}A_{\mu}\psi$$

that results from the fermionic part. Hence, $\mathcal{L}_{int} = -e\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}A_{\mu}\psi$ seems to do the trick. However, the scalar particle bit does not seem to trivially simplify, as there are some remaining terms:

$$ieA_{\mu}\left[\left(\partial^{\mu}\phi^*\right)\phi-\phi^*\partial^{\mu}\phi\right]+e^2A_{\mu}A^{\mu}\phi^*\phi$$

This would give $D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu}+ieA_{\mu}$.

Is my procedure correct? Is there a more intuitive way of solving this?

Edit: Corrected misuse of concepts as pointed in the comments.

Comment: How can the fields not be coupled if both have charges? Because A has spin 1?

Comment: @Duepietri My bad, wrong use of concepts. I should've said that there are no crossed terms between them. I apologise.

Comment: I would just comment for mu!

Comment: @Duepietri Already took care of that :)

Comment: Doesn't $\partial_{\mu}$ have to be replaced by the covariant derivative already in the free Lagrangian of the three free fields? When you gauge the free Dirac field this is introduced.

Comment: @Duepietri No, only after the gauge invariance is introduced!

Comment: I think you have to include all interactions first in the Lagrangian. Between A and the Dirac field and between A and the scalar field. And between the scalar field and the Dirac field (via A). This interacting Lagrangian you must gauge. As is done for the interacting Dirac field alone, for obtaining a massless A. Gauging the free dirac field gives a massless A. Gauging the interacting Lagrangian gives a covariant derivative.

Comment: @Duepietri I think I've never done something like that. I will look into it. Do you have any references that could be helpful?

Comment: Look how the Dirac Lagrangian is written here: https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node508.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Duepietri, I've come to a conclusion. Taking into account that $D_{\mu}$ needs to be gauge invariant, the minimal coupling

$$D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} + ieA_{\mu}$$

would give some remaining terms, of which we could compose an interaction:

$$\mathcal{L}_{int} = -e\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}A_{\mu}\psi -ieA_{\mu}\left[\left(\partial^{\mu}\phi^*\right)\phi-\phi^*\partial^{\mu}\phi\right]-e^2A_{\mu}A^{\mu}\phi^*\phi$$

since we can identify $\mathcal{L}_{free}$ with the same expression as in the original post, with $\partial_{\mu}$ instead of $D_{\mu}$.

For those who wish to read a bit more about this, I would recommend the online note by Matthew Schwartz (2012) on Scalar QED or his book, *Quantum Field Theory and The Standard Model* by Matthew D. Schwartz.